# Is there any indication what causes the holes in the spacetime fabric necessitating they be mapped by the supreme being?

Tags: time-travel, time-bandits

In the film *Time Bandits*, the group of dwarfs tell Kevin that they were once employed by the Supreme Being to repair holes in the spacetime fabric, but instead they realized the potential to use the map that identifies these holes to steal riches.

Their plot and adventures aside, is there ever any indication for the cause of these holes in the spacetime fabric?

Simply naturally occurring phenomena for which the Supreme Being needs to hire maintenance workers to assist in repairs, part of Evil’s plots against the Supreme Being? Something else?

Comment: There are apparently shooting scripts out there with a good bit of additional information (as well as a lot of snarky comments), but as far as I know, nothing available online.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the universe, according to Randall, has shoddy workmanship due to its [quick construction](https://media1.giphy.com/media/5xtDarowC2hP3f8EuwE/200w.gif?cid=82a1493bspkfuod4z7qzy1tuao55hxwwkd5n4818qt2z6qtl&rid=200w.gif&ct=g). Honestly, this should come as no surprise to those of us that live in it.

> ‘So,’ Randall continued, ‘to punish us, the Supreme being sent us down
> to the repairs department. **Between you and me, Kevin, being created so
> quickly and all, the universe is a bit of a botched job.** We discovered’ He lowered his voice confidentially - that there are holes in it.’
> 'Holes?' asked Kevin. ‘Yes. Holes in time and space. And we’ve got a map showing every one. We thought - thought - instead of repairing the holes, why not use them? Why not use this map - the only one in the
> universe - to get stinking rich!’
> ‘Yeah,’ said Strutter, ‘stinking
> rich!’
> Plucking an earthenware jar of wine from the wreckage, he broke
> the wax seal and began to pour the wine out into precious chalices,
> silver goblets and even a ruby-encrusted helmet.
> Raising high their
> vessels of wine, the dwarves all cried: Here’s to stinking rich!
>
> <sub><sup>[Time Bandits: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3419073-time-bandits)</sup></sub>

Comment: This seems to be the most technically-correct source reason.

Comment: This is what Randall *believes*, but it's also consistent with the theory that the Supreme Being was letting them come to wrong conclusions as part of his plan. He was at least pretty clearly encouraging the false idea that they had taken the map against his will--in earlier scenes when he was shown as a giant head pursuing them, he was [saying](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut23WARAm7A) "return what you have stolen from me", creating a different impression than his later statement "Of course you didn't mean to steal the map. I gave it to you, you silly man."

Comment: It is not the intent I’m sure, but a post hoc meaning could be the ill-gotten gains from their Time Banditry, and not the map per se. In this meaning, free will is given in the form of the map; the recipient could use it for ill or good.

Comment: I don't think it works to interpret the Supreme Being as telling them to return other loot they've stolen besides the map, since he specifically says "return what you have stolen *from me*". Also, he says this *before* the bandits do the Napoleon heist, and after they take the booty through the time hole and arrive in medieval England, Kevin asks "Is it always like this when you've done a raid?" and the bandits reveal that this was actually their first one, so they wouldn't have done any yet when we first saw the Supreme Being yelling at them.

Answer (score 21):

When the Supreme Being manifests at the end of the movie, he makes clear that both the existence of Evil and the use of the map by the bandits was all part of his plan to "test" his creation. I would presume this means that it was also part of the Supreme Being's plan that Evil would pursue the bandits in order to get the map for himself, so he could escape the Fortress of Ultimate Darkness and run rampant over creation. This would at least strongly imply that the existence of the holes themselves was part of the Supreme Being's plan to test creation, since the plan wouldn't work without them.

The key dialogue can be seen on the transcript pages [here](https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=time_bandits_21923&p=21) and [here](https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=time_bandits_21923&p=22). When the Supreme Being manifested, Randall tried to apologize by saying they didn't really mean to steal the map, and the Supreme Being said "Of course you didn't mean to steal the map. I gave it to you, you silly man." Then he added "I had to have some way of testing my handiwork. I think it turned out rather well ... Evil turned out rather well." Then Kevin spoke up, and referring to all the people who had been killed when the time bandits tried to round up people from throughout history to fight Evil, Kevin asked "You mean you let all those people die, just to test your creation?" and the Supreme Being replied "Yes. You really are a clever boy." This leads to a funny little theological joke where Kevin asks why there has to be evil at all, and the Supreme Being mutters absent-mindedly "I think it's something to do with free will."

This is in fact a [traditional theological response](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/#FreWil) to the [problem of evil](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/), one which tries to argue that a world in which at least some beings make good choices of their own free will is better than one where they are all predetermined to make only good choices, even if the former type of world leads to a great deal of suffering and death due to some making evil choices. In effect, the idea is that God wants us to face real choices between good and evil as a kind of test, much like the Supreme Being creating Evil and letting him pursue the map as some kind of test of the creation. The video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5K5ZVz45_o) talks a little more about the relation of the final scene to real theological arguments, and at 8:50 it also includes a quote from an interview with Terry Gilliam [here](https://www.csmonitor.com/1982/0107/010701.html) where he talks about how aspects of the movie grew out of his (and fellow script-writer Michael Palin's) religious education:

> The 'big questions' are always there for us. Michael and I had solid religious upbringings, so we grew up believing and thinking about God and religion and good and evil. I can't get those out of my system; they're a part of me. The normal approach in a kids' film is to make the final character a wizard. But why not bring God into it? Why not stop fiddling around, and get right down to things? The cosmic view appeals to me.

So it seems pretty clear that Gilliam was making a joke about the free will response to the problem of evil, and I think this makes it plausible that he would imagine the Supreme Being intentionally creating opportunities for Evil to run rampant as part of his testing our own ability to freely avoid evil.

Comment: One reason why I’ve held on to the possibility that it wasn’t all planned is the mumbling about free will. What if the supreme being is more or less lying about having everything planned to cover up his incompetence? The thing about the holes and the map being definitely part of the plan is how that fits with the time bandits having free will. The pink bunkadoo is something I think about a lot, because they were allowed to design it, but clearly it was never manifested on earth. Was it edited out of creation by a competent deity or does it exist on some planet hidden from a naive deity?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I imagine the time bandits had some kind of cosmic workshop but the Supreme Being had to approve their test models before they were "implemented" on Earth. I agree the movie leaves open the possibility that the Supreme Being isn't really omniscient/omnipotent, but the way he was able to easily dispose of Evil suggests to me that he is vastly powerful and probably it wouldn't have been so easy for the bandits to escape him in his giant floating head form if he really wanted the map back immediately. Plus the theological joke works better if he does have the attributes of God IMO.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Alternatively, the mumbling may be because the supreme being is not happy that he **has to** allow evil in order to allow free will. It's just like some mathematicians might not be happy that Godel's incompleteness theorem is true, and only grudgingly accept it because it is a fact. Note that he cannot be 100% omniscient if there is true free will, and that really is the key point.

Answer (score 6):

I assume this is intentionally left ambiguous, and a theme of the movie is the imperfections of a “divine” creation.

Recall how Evil talks about how foolish the supreme being has been in how he created the universe. Slugs are one example.

And also recall how at the end, the supreme being says that Evil turned out pretty well. The idea being that the events of the film were part of a test of how Evil interacted with the rest of creation.

If the supreme being is omniscient and omnipotent (implied but never stated), then it’s reasonable to conclude that the holes in the fabric of the universe and the “loss” of the map and the hijinks of the time bandits are all part of the master plan for the supreme being’s creation.

So you can either conclude that the so-called supreme being is just as thoughtless and barely competent as any middle manager, or that he is actually supreme and everything went more or less the way he intended.

The very end could justify the incompetence interpretation, or add cold heartedness to the omnipotent interpretation.